# 'Private' Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, hosting

I'm currently making study guides/tests for students on Jupyter Notebook and need to figure out a way to launch it to them on a browser. I've been using Mybinder.org to pull from my Git, however I store many study guides/tests on the path that is shown when they load up the link created from Mybinder.org. I don't want them just finding my Git (private Git doesn't work with my Binder) and looking at future class information.

Is anyone aware of any website's that would pull from my Git but not show the path? I know this a weird ask, as I've been searching the web for a few hours and have had no luck.

Comment: i would put the study guides in a different repo